# How to write super simple custom relay chain

Tags: polkadot, xcmp, hrmp

EDIT #2: TLDR Is it possible to write a bare bones version of polkadot relay chain that only has cross chain communication (HRMP) + consensus (BABE+Grandpa) but doesn't have anything else (no governance, etc)?

I'm pretty new to substrate + polkadot and I am trying to develop my own super simple relay chain from the node template (https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template). Right now, I am just trying to implement the hrmp protocol for xcm messaging between relay chain and future parachains. Anyone with any ideas how to approach this? I am currently looking at polkadot source code and trying to add the

`Hrmp: parachains_hrmp::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config} = 60,`

line from `polkadot/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs` to my `substrate-node-template/runtime/lib.rs`. I tried to add all the dependencies by cloning the `/runtime/parachains`, `/primitives`, `/core-primitives`, and a couple others but I just get too many dependency errors to manage.

EDIT: The specific error I am getting is this, looks like the versions for zstd is messed up, no idea how I got this or how to fix it

```
error: failed to select a version for `zstd`.
    ... required by package `sp-maybe-compressed-blob v4.1.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sp-maybe-compressed-blob` of package `sc-executor-common v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-executor-common` of package `sc-executor v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-executor` of package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/stevenyao/Development/learning/substrate/substrate-node-template/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.9.0` are: 0.9.2+zstd.1.5.1, 0.9.1+zstd.1.5.1, 0.9.0+zstd.1.5.0

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `zstd v0.10.0+zstd.1.5.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `zstd = "^0.10.0"` of package `sp-maybe-compressed-blob v4.1.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=master#4aec7b4d)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sp-maybe-compressed-blob` (locked to 4.1.0-dev) of package `substrate-wasm-builder v5.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=master#4aec7b4d)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `substrate-wasm-builder` (locked to 5.0.0-dev) of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/stevenyao/Development/learning/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime/relay)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/stevenyao/Development/learning/substrate/substrate-node-template/node)`

failed to select a version for `zstd` which could resolve this conflict
```

Comment: I've had the same idea and managed to make it work somehow. Maybe it can help.
https://github.com/buraktabn/relay-chain

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: When compiling it, it looks like there are some errors from [these lines](https://github.com/buraktabn/relay-chain/blob/main/node/service/src/lib.rs#L664-L666)

It looks a bit incomplete here. What were you going for in these lines?

Comment: Ah, I must have forgotten those in there. I had an idea if I could have another block production service running alongside it (only to have a consensus over RPC calls so clients would have easy access). Ditched the idea for now :) Remove those lines and it'll compile. `./target/release/polkadot --chain kusama-dev --tmp --alice` to run.

Comment: Thanks again! I have a question regarding the spec files you included. It looks like you have a customSpec.json, and a kusama.json. 

Is kusama.json the spec that is used when you run ```./target/release/polkadot --chain kusama-dev --tmp --alice```? Where is are the raw specs stored?

Comment: How would I create a parachain to this relay chain? Following the [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/connect-parachain), I'm up to the step:

```./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \..
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain <relay chain raw chain spec> \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977```

What would I use for the relay chain raw chain spec? I tried kusama dev and got error ```Invalid input: `kusama-dev` only supported with `kusama-native` feature enabled.")```

Comment: I haven't exported any chain-spec, Those are from polkadot and substrate. You can find [here](https://github.com/buraktabn/relay-chain/blob/baefae02ef015383afabdc689aa635c3c53c4a5a/node/cli/src/command.rs#L87) for the configs. As for the parachains, I've never tried to run parachain on it. Maybe generate spec for `kusama-dev` and make sure the node running with the same chain spec as well. `./target/release/polkadot build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain kusama-dev > customSpec.json`